# C quantidade de alunos aprovados reprovados

Tags: c, for

Por favor, preciso que o programa total de quantidade de alunos aprovados reprovados e de substitutiva

Elaborar programa C para calcular e exibir a média de 3 alunos de uma determinada disciplina.
A média aritmética simples é calculada a partir da leitura de 2 notas. Para cada aluno: - exibir a mensagem "APROVADO" se a média obtida for igual ou maior do que 6.

- exibir a mensagem "SUBSTITUTIVA se a média obtida for maior ou igual a 3 e menor do que 6. - exibir a mensagem "REPROVADO" se a média obtida for menor do que 3.

Ao final, exibir a quantidade de alunos aprovados, de alunos que farão a substitutiva e os alunos reprovados.

Consegui até aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i;
int aprovado = 0;
int reprovado = 0;
int substitutiva = 0;

float n1,n2,m;
printf("informe as notas dos alunos: \n");

for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    printf("\n\nnotas do aluno %i\n",i);
    scanf("%f %f", &n1,&n2);
    m=(n1+n2)/2;
    if(m>=6)
        printf("aluno aprovado - media %.2f",m);
        aprovado = aprovado++;
        else if(m>=3)
            printf("fazer substitutiva - media %.2f",m);
            substitutiva = substitutiva++;
            else
                printf("aluno reprovado - media %.2f",m);
                reprovado = reprovado++;


        }

printf("Alunos Aprovados %d", aprovado);
printf("Alunos Reprovados %d", reprovado);
printf("Alunos Substitutiva %d", substitutiva);
for(i = 1; i <=3; i++)
    
    
return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Caso o que deve ser executado com condição de um `if` for mais de um comando então você precisa colocar os comandos em um bloco `{...}`.
O operador de incremento `k++;` é equivalente a `k = k + 1;` portanto não faça outra atribuição.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

int i;
int aprovado = 0;
int reprovado = 0;
int substitutiva = 0;

float n1,n2,m;
printf("informe as notas dos alunos: \n");

for(i=1;i<=3;i++){
    printf("\n\nnotas do aluno %i\n",i);
    scanf("%f %f", &n1,&n2);
    m=(n1+n2)/2;
    if(m>=6) {
        printf("aluno aprovado - media %.2f",m);
        aprovado++;
    }
    else 
        if(m>=3) {
            printf("fazer substitutiva - media %.2f",m);
            substitutiva++;
        }
        else {
            printf("aluno reprovado - media %.2f",m);
            reprovado++;
        }
    }
    printf("Alunos Aprovados %d", aprovado);
    printf("Alunos Reprovados %d", reprovado);
    printf("Alunos Substitutiva %d", substitutiva);
    return 0;
}
```